Unable to connect Mongoose to my node.js application
I am trying to install mongoose on my node.js application, and I am getting this error. I have tried changing everything including changing the IP to "Allow access from everywhere." My current IP is whitelisted as well. I still don't know why I am getting the below error message.


const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const dns = require('dns');
dns.setDefaultResultOrder('ipv4first');

const app = express();
mongoose.set('debug', true);
mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://username:password@tryingip.vfri4.mongodb.net/myDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority", {
    serverSelectionTimeoutMS: 5000 // Set a timeout limit for connection attempts
})
.then(() => console.log("Connected to MongoDB Atlas"))
.catch(err => console.error("Connection error:", err));



This is the error that I am getting:
MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/security-whitelist/
    at _handleConnectionErrors (/Users/adityaverma/Desktop/trying ass8/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:909:11)
    at NativeConnection.openUri (/Users/adityaverma/Desktop/trying ass8/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:860:11) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
    servers: Map(3) {
      'mongo8-shard-00-02.hu8hm.mongodb.net:27017' => ServerDescription {
        address: 'mongo8-shard-00-02.hu8hm.mongodb.net:27017',
        type: 'Unknown',
        hosts: [],
        passives: [],
        arbiters: [],
        tags: {},
        minWireVersion: 0,
        maxWireVersion: 0,
        roundTripTime: -1,
        minRoundTripTime: 0,
        lastUpdateTime: 791219720,
        lastWriteDate: 0,
        error: MongoNetworkError: 409CBCD701000000:error:0A000438:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert internal error:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1605:SSL alert number 80
        
            at connectionFailureError (/Users/adityaverma/Desktop/trying ass8/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connect.js:356:20)
            at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (/Users/adityaverma/Desktop/trying ass8/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connect.js:272:44)
            at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
            at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
            at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
            at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
            at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
          [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(1) { 'ResetPool' },
          [cause]: [Error: 409CBCD701000000:error:0A000438:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert internal error:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1605:SSL alert number 80
          ] {
            library: 'SSL routines',
            reason: 'tlsv1 alert internal error',
            code: 'ERR_SSL_TLSV1_ALERT_INTERNAL_ERROR'
          }
        },
        topologyVersion: null,
        setName: null,
        setVersion: null,
        electionId: null,
        logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
        maxMessageSizeBytes: null,
        maxWriteBatchSize: null,
        maxBsonObjectSize: null,
        primary: null,
        me: null,
        '$clusterTime': null
      },
      'mongo8-shard-00-00.hu8hm.mongodb.net:27017' => ServerDescription {
        address: 'mongo8-shard-00-00.hu8hm.mongodb.net:27017',
        type: 'Unknown',
        hosts: [],
        passives: [],
        arbiters: [],
        tags: {},
        minWireVersion: 0,
        maxWireVersion: 0,
        roundTripTime: -1,
        minRoundTripTime: 0,
        lastUpdateTime: 791219875,
        lastWriteDate: 0,
        error: MongoNetworkError: 409CBCD701000000:error:0A000438:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert internal error:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1605:SSL alert number 80
        
            at connectionFailureError (/Users/adityaverma/Desktop/trying ass8/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connect.js:356:20)
            at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (/Users/adityaverma/Desktop/trying ass8/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connect.js:272:44)
            at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
            at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
            at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
            at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
            at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
          [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(1) { 'ResetPool' },
          [cause]: [Error: 409CBCD701000000:error:0A000438:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert internal error:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1605:SSL alert number 80
          ] {
            library: 'SSL routines',
            reason: 'tlsv1 alert internal error',
            code: 'ERR_SSL_TLSV1_ALERT_INTERNAL_ERROR'
          }
        },
        topologyVersion: null,
        setName: null,
        setVersion: null,
        electionId: null,
        logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
        maxMessageSizeBytes: null,
        maxWriteBatchSize: null,
        maxBsonObjectSize: null,
        primary: null,
        me: null,
        '$clusterTime': null
      },
      'mongo8-shard-00-01.hu8hm.mongodb.net:27017' => ServerDescription {
        address: 'mongo8-shard-00-01.hu8hm.mongodb.net:27017',
        type: 'Unknown',
        hosts: [],
        passives: [],
        arbiters: [],
        tags: {},
        minWireVersion: 0,
        maxWireVersion: 0,
        roundTripTime: -1,
        minRoundTripTime: 0,
        lastUpdateTime: 791219524,
        lastWriteDate: 0,
        error: MongoNetworkError: 409CBCD701000000:error:0A000438:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert internal error:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1605:SSL alert number 80
        
            at connectionFailureError (/Users/adityaverma/Desktop/trying ass8/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connect.js:356:20)
            at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (/Users/adityaverma/Desktop/trying ass8/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connect.js:272:44)
            at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
            at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
            at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
            at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
            at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
          [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(1) { 'ResetPool' },
          [cause]: [Error: 409CBCD701000000:error:0A000438:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert internal error:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1605:SSL alert number 80
          ] {
            library: 'SSL routines',
            reason: 'tlsv1 alert internal error',
            code: 'ERR_SSL_TLSV1_ALERT_INTERNAL_ERROR'
          }
        },
        topologyVersion: null,
        setName: null,
        setVersion: null,
        electionId: null,
        logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
        maxMessageSizeBytes: null,
        maxWriteBatchSize: null,
        maxBsonObjectSize: null,
        primary: null,
        me: null,
        '$clusterTime': null
      }
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: 'atlas-9q7qfy-shard-0',
    maxElectionId: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
  },
  code: undefined
}

I am on Node.js v18.16.0

This question is similar to: getting ReplicaSetNoPrimary and MongoServerSelectionError error while connecting MongoDB with nodejs. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

80 here is TLS1_AD_INTERNAL_ERROR (see openssl/tls1.h) which doesn't say much

Some ideas from a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62153541/2282634
